# Converting NVARCHAR to datetime Keeps Failing

Tags: sql

I have a field which is an `NVARCHAR` format. It sometimes has a `date` in it, depending on the format of another field.

I am trying to `convert` it to a `datetime` field, if the field next to it = 'DAT'. so my statement is

```
  SELECT XV_Type, CASE XV_Type='DAT' THEN 
  CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,XV_Data),105) 
  ELSE XV_Data END 
  FROM MyTable
```

I get an error converting aNVARCHAR to DATETIME but it wont tell me why.... :(

Comment: what is the error? which is your `RDMBS`?

Comment: you missed `when` in your `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to revise your code into:

`SELECT XV_Type, CASE WHEN XV_Type='DAT' THEN XV_Data
  ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,XV_Data),105) END 
  FROM MyTable`

don't expect the sql to convert the 'DAT' string into DATE.